# Setting up tomcat 8.5 APR https connection

Tags: apr, tomcat8.5

I've been trying to setup my tomcat for HTTPS connectivity using APR library and I've already downloaded the `tcnative-1.dll` from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi) and placed that inside my tomcat lib directory (Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin) and modified my server.xml to use this connector configuration:

```xml
<Connector port="8443"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <UpgradeProtocol compression="on" className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>
    <SSLHostConfig honorCipherOrder="false">
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="C:\wew\keystore\mysitename.key"
                     certificateFile="C:\wew\keystore\mysitename.crt"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

This error appears when I try to start tomcat [tomcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9JQr.png) which is probably due to the library not found. Can anyone help me on this? Am I missing something? I'm fairly new to this so I'm really confused.